# Use docker-build.yaml environment variable in angular package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to get the access token that is available in docker-build.yaml as an environemnt variable to package.json in my angular project

I am basically trying to get that auth token to access a private repository and install as a dependency

"repo_name": "https://github.com/<>:_authToken=${env.NPM_TOKEN}",

something like this. when I tried this, it didn't work as the env.NPM_token is not received.

So trying to see how to get that value in package.json

Answer (score 0):

So, first and foremost; you should never expose sensitive information like this in an `ENV` or `ARG` variable, as they will be easily found by anyone.

A way around this is to use so-called docker secrets. Since you're using yaml, you have it relatively easy.

```
version: '3'

secrets:
  npm_token:
    file: ./token_on_host_system.txt

services:
  node:
  image: nodejs
  secrets: 
    - npm_token
  environment:
    - NPM_TOKEN_FILE=/run/secrets/npm_token
```

now, the `NPM_TOKEN_FILE` env variable will point to the file containing your secret. You can now `cat` this file and use it in your scripts using `sed` or your tool of preference.